# I get data of last form in django when I am using pagination

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

**views.py**

```
def quiz (request):
    questions = Question.objects.order_by("?")[0:101]
    paginator = Paginator(questions , 1)
    page_number = request.GET.get("page")
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number) 


    if request.method == "POST" : 
            user_timer = request.POST.get("timer")
            total=len(questions)
            score=0
            wrong=0
            correct=0
    
            for q in questions : 
                user_answer = request.POST.get(str(q.pk))
                if user_answer :
    
                        print(user_answer)
                        if q.answer == user_answer : 
                            score += 5  
                            correct += 1
                        else : 
                            wrong += 1
                            score += 0
                    
                        percent = correct / total * 100
                        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
                        profile.score += score # type: ignore
                        profile.save()
                        context={'score':score , 'wrong':wrong, 'correct':correct,'percent' : percent, 'timer':user_timer , 'total' : total}
                        
                        return render(request, "quizApp/result.html", context)         
                
    
    return render(request, "quizApp/quiz.html", {"paginator":paginator , "page_obj":page_obj, "questions":questions})
```

How I get marge two forms in pagination ?

I want get answers of form has pagination but I get data of last form in pagination.

How can I do this ?